# Next JS Routing with Link Component in Production

Tags: next.js, routes, vercel, production, next-link

I have a simple NextJS 14 app (I am new to NextJS) I have set a simple web app with 3 routes for testing I have developed the route page it contains 1 background video and few images.
I did deploy the app using Vercel CLI 33.0.1.

For the navigation between routes I am using the next Link component nothing too fancy.

```
<Link href="/about">About</Link>
```

In dev mode the navigation is perfect. But when I deploy to vercel in production mode the /about page loads in minutes (3min) In the mean time the whole app freezes...

I have tried to fix the issue using a simple Anchor tag but no I want to stick to the Link component and understand why the hell it take 5 min to render a simple page.

https://sea-lab.vercel.app/

you can have a look there

About page :

```
function About() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>We are testing this route :/ </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
export default About
```

Header component (the navigation bar)

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { ModeToggle } from "../theme-toggler";

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header className="...">
            <Link href="/" className="...">
                Quantum
            </Link>
            <div className="...">
                <Link href="/service" className="...">Service</Link>
                <a href="/team" className="...">Team</a>
                <Link href="/about" className="...">About</Link>
                <Link href="/contact" className="...">Contact</Link>
                <ModeToggle />
            </div>
        </header>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

The main page component

```
import Header from "@/components/Header/Header";

return (
      <div>
        <Header />
      </div>
    )
```

Again in local using

```
npm run dev
```

this works fine but as soon as i deploy to firebase or vercel
It's not working anymore for more detail code
you can clone my github

```
https://github.com/Ahmed-UPEC/sea-lab
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: can you post the code for the about page?

Comment: We need more information to be able to assist. Show sample code of the about page and also show any other special configs you have. Add the file structure too

Comment: I have edited the question you can take a look into it

Answer (score 0):

Ok for anyone using Framer with NextJS be careful, I was playing with svg animation to make some animation running for ever, I was using a while true loop on the landing page. When dealing with NextJS route make sure to not have any animations running in a Infinite loop.

So address this issue I replace the while true by a for loop with X iterations.
This way the Link component was Working fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).